# Mongodb text search not working using the $text operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I am using mongoose behind the scene and trying to implement text search for multiple fields. I came across [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) and did the following

Student model:

```
const Student = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    code: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

Student.index({ name: 'text', code: 'text' });
const StudentModel = mongoose.model('Student', Student);
module.exports = StudentModel;
```

and then in my controller I made the query like this

```
 const [result, err] = await of(
    await Student.find({
      $text: { $search: req.query.term },
    }).limit(10)
  );

  console.log('result', result);
```

which always result in empty array. My student collection is of the form

```
[{name: 'abc def', code: 'a0.1'},{name: 'ghi jkl', code: 'a0.2'}]
```

what I am trying to do is to search for **a0.2 ghi** to result in `{name: 'ghi jkl', code: 'a0.2'}`. Any idea what i'm trying wrong?

Comment: @turivishal no it is returning result which does not even meet the query :(

Comment: showing correct result, that is the result for text `a0`, it will consider `dot` as delimiter, see [Tokenization Delimiters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters) in text search index.

Comment: I understand that point but it is also showing objects with a0.1 while i searched for a0.2

Comment: see the comment again it is result for `a0`, the `dot` is a delimiter and search will consider `a0` and `1` both as separate words..

Comment: oh okay, i get your point. so how do i change it to get the desired result as I mentioned in question

Comment: You should sanitize the search query before searching. You can use regex for that. In javascript, do this `term.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "")`

Comment: @ImranNaqvi does my answer help you to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note in [Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#-text-operator),

> `$text` will tokenize the search string using whitespace and most punctuation as delimiters, and perform a logical OR of all such tokens in the search string.

Note in [Tokenization Delimiters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters),

> *Changed in version 3.2.*
>
> For tokenization, version 3 text index uses the delimiters categorized under Dash, Hyphen, Pattern_Syntax, Quotation_Mark, Terminal_Punctuation, and White_Space in [Unicode 8.0 Character Database Prop List](http://www.unicode.org/Public/8.0.0/ucd/PropList.txt).

There is a closed issue [SERVER-13099](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13099) - *Expand set of delimiters recognized by text search tokenizer.*

As per the above details the `dot` . is a Tokenization Delimiter and your query for `a0.2` considers as a two separate words like `a0` and `2`.

---

You can try [Exact Phrase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/#exact-phrase) match, and see more about [Phrases](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#phrases),
you need to prepare phrase `\"a0.2\"` to ignore delimiter,

The search string should be,

```
.find({ $text: { $search: "\"a0.2\" ghi" } })
```

---

You can try a JS logic to prepare phrase and ignore `dot` . delimiter,

```
let term = req.query.term; // "a0.2 ghi"
let searchTerm = "";
term.split(" ").forEach(function(s) {
    if (s.search(/\./) !== -1) { s = "\""+s+"\""; }
    searchTerm += s + " ";
});

// now the string is ""a0.2" ghi"
await Student.find({ $text: { $search: searchTerm.trim() } }).limit(10);
```